# With Symfony 2.2 and Doctrine 2.2.* I can't save manyToMany relations with cascade: persist

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, save, relation

I try to use Doctrine casecade feature tu automagicaly save relations between two entities, and it does'nt seem to work.

I've made a demo here : https://github.com/asakurayoh/demo_bug_doctrine
So I use the doctrine fixture to make my demo.
you need to create de database (app/console doctrine:database:create), migrate the tables (app/console doctrine:migrations:migrate) and then, load the fixtures (app/console doctrine:fixtures:load). The third fixture (src/Demo/MyBundle/DataFixtures/ORM/TagsNewsFixtures.php) is adding all tags entities to all the news. And if you go to the database, you will see that no relation was save in the news_tag table... I think my relation are well defined in my mapping (Resources/config/doctrine/News.orm.yml and Tag.orm.yml) and the cascade property is set.

Someone can find the problem with this code? I search everywhere (stackoverflow too) and I've done everythings everyone said... it should work...

Thanks to save my life (and my entities relations, ha!)

AsakuraYoh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.
The "joinTable" preperty need to be on the News side and news use the "inversedBy" property, no the MappedBy (that's the tag). So it work. And to add news to a tag (do the inverse, then), we need to specify in the Tag entity to add the tag to the news... I don't understand why Doctrine doesn't do that by default... weird...

Comment: Can you please provide a test case for this behaviour and (if confirmed, with mapping validation passing) post it to http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in fixtures loading order - `TagNewsFixtures` is loaded first, therefore no tag nor news are in database at that time. Try forcing load order using ordere

```
namespace Acme\HelloBundle\DataFixtures\ORM;

use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\AbstractFixture;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\OrderedFixtureInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;

class LoadData extends AbstractFixture implements OrderedFixtureInterface
{
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public function getOrder()
    {
        return 1; // the order in which fixtures will be loaded
    }
}
```

Comment: I jsut verify this, and my fixtures are loading in this order (in my case) : 1. NewsFixture, 2. TagFixtures, 3. TagNewsFixtures... I dump the value of the news and tags in my TagNewsFixture to be sure... So that's not it...

Comment: I've add the OrderedFixtureInterface to my fixture and set the order, just to be safe, but on my server, the order was already right.

Comment: I use the same way as show here (sorry, in french): http://www.siteduzero.com/informatique/tutoriels/developpez-votre-site-web-avec-le-framework-symfony2/relation-many-to-many-1
But it's the same things in every tutorial that I find.